# Rails Non Standard Resource Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to create a route that's like this:

`https://example.com/appusers/1/check_for_updates`.

It should basically be a resourced route so that I can do `@appuser = Appuser.find(params[:id])`

But I can't figure out how to list that in my routes file.

I've tried `get 'appusers/:id/check_for_updates'` but that throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `:member`

```
resources :appusers do
  get :check_for_updates, on: :member
end
```

[Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)